# How to avoid assigning the index of selected drop box item when inserted to db instead of actual value in drop box?

Tags: laravel-5

```
 {!! Form::select('subject', array('' => 'Select A Subject')+$subject, null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Above is the drop box code. That takes values from db and display correctly at the drop box. But after it is selected it gets the index.The inspect of that output as follows.

```
<select class="form-control" name="subject"><option value="" selected="selected">Select A Subject</option><option value="1">English</option><option value="3">Environmental Studies</option><option value="2">Maths</option></select>
```

How to fix that problem?

Comment: means you cant able to keep selected your choosed option?

Comment: No. I want to set the option value as drop box values

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$subList = ['' => 'Select A Subject'] +$subject;

 {!! Form::select('name', $subList , Input::old('name') , array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
```

Comment: What did u mean by id. Was it a name of drop box?

Comment: instant of id you can use name or else. as per your requirment

Comment: Still for the option value it will display the id of retrieving row of database